# dblclick event is triggered after jquery drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a double click event to a jquery connected list item. I add the double click event as shown below;

```
$(a_elements[i]).dblclick(duplicate_building(a_elements[i]));
```

this is part of a function that is run after an li drop and loops through each element using the a_elements array. the problem is that once I drop the element in the list the function "duplicate_building" runs anyway, even though I only dropped the element in to the list and that 's just using a single click anyway, can anyone tell me why the double click event is running without a double click and how to stop it?

Many thanks in advance if anyone can spot my mistake

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger the double click event like:

```
$('selector_to_target').trigger('dblclick');
```

#### According to comment

You can try this:

```
$('boby').on('dblclick', a_elements[i], duplicate_building(a_elements[i]));
```

Comment: hi sorry if i wasn't clear i want almost the opposite, the function runs when i haven't double clicked on it it is running when i drag the element in to a list, any ideas?

Comment: thanks for the update but the duplicate_building function still runs when the element is dropped

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem it's because I needed to declare the function call inside a jquery function as below;

$(a_elements[i]).dblclick(function () {duplicate_building(this)});

this meant that duplicate_building only ran on double click and not when the event is declared

thanks for you help though thecodeparadox